# Check that each object ID contains one value mandatory

Tags: sql

I have a DB structure like:

| Account | Product Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Primary |
| 1 | Addon |
| 2 | Addon |
| 3 | Addon |
| 4 | Primary |
| 4 | Addon |

I want to write an SQL which gives me those accounts which do not have Primary. For ex, the above should return 2 and 3

Comment: Which DBMS? `EXCEPT` is a common way to achieve this, but there are others.

Comment: What is stopping you? What problem do you have with your existing query (which you forgot to include)?

Comment: Im using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Actually i dont know how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

The `MINUS` operator is a common way to accomplish this in Oracle:

```
select account from my_table where product_type <> 'Primary'
minus
select account from my_table where product_type = 'Primary'
```

You could also use the `HAVING` clause with conditional aggregation:

```
select account
from my_table
group by account
having sum(case when product_type = 'Primary' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PvxtYJRk) for demo.

**EDIT**: Updated answers above as I somehow imagined more than you originally asked.

Comment: From the problem description I can't say confidently whether "Addon" is actually necessary.

Comment: I must have added that requirement in my own mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`. For example:

```
select *
from (select distinct account from t) a
where not exists (
  select 1
  from t
  where t.account = a.account and t.product_type = 'Primary'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

since you did not specify which DBMS you are using. there is an example on SQL. hope it will help
simple way:

```
declare @t table (Account int, ProductType varchar(20))

insert into @t Values
(1  ,'Primary')
,(1 ,'Addon')
,(2 ,'Addon')
,(3 ,'Addon')
,(4 ,'Primary')
,(4 ,'Addon')
select * from @t where account not in (
    select account from @t where ProductType ='Primary'
)
```

complex

```
declare @t table (Account int, ProductType varchar(20))

insert into @t Values
(1  ,'Primary')
,(1 ,'Addon')
,(2 ,'Addon')
,(3 ,'Addon')
,(4 ,'Primary')
,(4 ,'Addon')

;with CTE as(
select account from @t
)
select * from @t where account not in (
select 
    CA.Account
from CTE
CROSS APPLY (select top (1) t.Account from @t as t where CTE.Account = t.Account and t.ProductType = 'Primary' ) as CA
)
```

result:

[image]